# How to disable event listener for socket when user disconnects?

Tags: node.js, twitter, socket.io

I'm using the Twit library for Node.js, and I begin by creating a stream of incoming tweets here:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { locations: allLocations })
```

Then, using Socket.io, I send the tweets to each connected client, and also log when a user disconnects:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("User disconnected!!!!!"); 
  });
  stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
    // sends tweet to client in question:
    socket.emit('info', tweet);
  });
}
```

The problem is that even after a user disconnects, the tweets meant for them still keep getting parsed by the event listener, and logged to the console. Is there a way to "disable" all socket-related event listeners when the user disconnects? Or is there a cleaner way to handle this situation with streaming tweets?

Comment: Why not to destroy stream on disconnect event?

Comment: @SalvadorDali - Need to have it running for the users that are still connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("User disconnected!!!!!"); 
    stream.removeListener('tweet', onTweet);
  });
  function onTweet(tweet) {
    // sends tweet to client in question:
    socket.emit('info', tweet);
  }
  stream.on('tweet', onTweet);
}
```

Also, you could just broadcast to all sockets using a single 'tweet' event handler instead of adding a new 'tweet' event handler for every connection.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think your code would work, because the `stream.removeListener` might remove some other user's tweet listener. But I think you're on to something with the single 'tweet' event handler idea. I was thinking about putting all active sockets into an array, then iterating through them in the 'tweet' event handler to send the messages to all clients. That way, you only need a single handler.

Comment: Gonna give it a shot and report back

Comment: The `onTweet` is created per connection and is local per connection. So when the socket disconnects, it will have the correct reference when removing the listener. It's the same thing that you were doing before, except the anonymous function was pulled out and named (so it could be removed easily).

Comment: Gotcha. I tried it and I think this is just what I needed to do